# JobRepository on JBatch

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jbatch

I need to configure a job-repository in jbatch, beacause I need to set a custom datasource. I'm not able to understand how code its xml and where I have to put it in my project.

```
<job-repository id="jobRepository"
    data-source="dataSource"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager"    
    table-prefix="JCG_BATCH_"
    max-varchar-length="1000"/>
```

I think that the code I need should be looking similar to this one ( but this is Spring Batch that i cannot use )

Answer (score 1):

To set a custom datasource you should create a batch-config.properties at the path  META-INF/services.

And there you can set your new datasource:

```
JNDI_NAME= your datasource
```